# When I click the Log In button, the page just refreshes. Why?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium ChromeDriver nuget package with C#. Every time I click Log In, the page just refreshes and nothing happens. When I manually click it works fine.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();

            // opening chrome
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");

            // opening adp site
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://workforcenow.adp.com/workforcenow/login.html");

            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            // typing username 
            IWebElement usernameElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("user_id"));
            usernameElement.Click();
            foreach(var letter in Username)
            {
                usernameElement.SendKeys(letter.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            //todo: typing password
            IWebElement passwordElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
            passwordElement.Click();
            foreach (var letter in Password)
            {
                passwordElement.SendKeys(letter.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            //todo: click sign in
            IWebElement signInElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("subBtn"));
            signInElement.Click();


            Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try clicking using the Javascript executor?

IJavaScriptExecutor executor = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver);
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();",signInElement );

Comment: Yep, still didn't work :( the particular site does not like Selenium